# Fantasy book where a black fog chokes out a city surrounding a castle

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

Here is what I remember: it probably wasn't the first book in the series, and was probably near the end of the book itself. I believe I remember something about flying, perhaps dragons. Lots of magic. The people stormed the castle entrance trying to flee the black fog, which would turn them into zombie like creatures(?). Might just kill them.

Comment: Hi, Guest, welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please go over [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) and add as much additional information as you can.